# python + sqlite3: using IS NOT in a join query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

This works the way I expect (c is a cursor)

```
    c.execute('''SELECT e1.file, e1.sourceUrl, e1.rev 
        FROM externals1 AS e1
        LEFT JOIN externals as e0
        ON (e1.file = e0.file)
        AND (e1.rev <> e0.rev)
    ''')
```

but I get an error here:

```
    c.execute('''SELECT e1.file, e1.sourceUrl, e1.rev 
        FROM externals1 AS e1
        LEFT JOIN externals as e0
        ON (e1.file = e0.file)
        AND (e1.rev IS NOT e0.rev)
    ''')
```

with the message

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near "e0": syntax error
```

What's going on? I want to handle the case where e0.rev is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e1.file, e1.sourceUrl, e1.rev 
    FROM externals1 AS e1
    LEFT JOIN externals as e0
    ON (e1.file = e0.file)
    AND (e1.rev IS NOT NULL)
```

NULL means 'unassigned or unknown value', and as such can never be equal or not equal to something else. (How can something unknown or unassigned be compared to something else unknown or unassigned?) Therefore, you can't use `<>` or `=` to test them; you have to use the special operators IS/IS NOT instead.

You can also use

```
NOT (e1.rev = e0.rev)
```

if you're wanting to test for non-equality.

Comment: Note (as to why this syntax is valid): The constructs are `operand IS NULL` and `operand IS NOT NULL`. However, this isn't the same as query #1?

Comment: @pst: I'm not sure what you're asking. `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` isn't the same as the `<>` in the OP's first query at all. I'll add an explanation about the operands for NULL.

Comment: @Ken White I was/am confused about the question -- I'm not sure what the operator was looking for, but this answer is accepted so it must have been desired :P

Comment: I was confusing the "COL1 IS NOT COL2" idiom with the "COL1 IS NOT NULL" in a select/join.

Comment: ...so this answer made me realize I wanted something slightly different than what I asked for (namely some of the tests should have been in the WHERE clause rather than the JOIN clause)

Comment: @Jason S The SQL engine/planner/optimizer is free to move about expressions as long as it can guarantee semantic. Putting the conditional in a where vs. keeping it in the join is often a human comfort -- so write it comfortably (and easy to read/maintain :-)

Answer (score 2):

`!=` is ANSI for not equals, what you posted in the second example is invalid SQL for any database I know of.  You could try:

```
   SELECT e1.file, e1.sourceUrl, e1.rev 
     FROM externals1 AS e1
LEFT JOIN externals as e0 ON e0.file = e1.file
                         AND e1.rev NOT IN (e0.rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.file, e1.sourceUrl, e1.rev 
FROM externals1 AS e1
LEFT JOIN externals as e0
  ON e0.file = e1.file
  AND e1.rev <> e0.rev
  AND e1.rev IS NOT NULL
```

The constructs are `operand IS NULL` and `operand IS NOT NULL` (there is only *one operand* to either the `IS NUll`/`IS NOT NULL` *operators*!) -- I imagine the NULL-check in addition to a 'not' is desired but it's hard to tell from the question.

Remember, `x <> y` is always true when either (or both) `x` or `y` are `NULL`. (At least for an SQL89-compliant engine.)

Happy SQL'ing.

Addition: The [Wikipedia article on NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) is an interesting read, in general. It talks about some of the base NULL constructs (which may or may not entirely apply to a particular DB...)